# Question about parameter

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, affine-varieties

> Let $f=-y^n+x^{n-1}-1$ and $U=Z(f)$. Show that for all $P \in U \cap
> D(x)$ where $D(x)= \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{A}^2| x \neq 0\}$, $y-y(P)$ is a parameter or uniformiser at $P$.

We have $\dfrac{\partial f}{ \partial x}(P) \neq 0$ for all $P\in U \cap D(x)$. To indicate $y-y(P)$ is a parameter, i want to show that $y-y(P) \notin \mathfrak{m}_P^2$ where $\mathfrak{m}_P$ is an maximal ideal of $P$ in $\mathcal{O}_X(U \cap D(x))$. Now we have 
$$\mathcal{O}_X(U \cap D(x))= \dfrac{k[x,y,z]}{(zx-1,-y^n+x^{n-1}-1)}$$
How can we find the maximal ideal in this quotient ring?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at the nullstellensatz, for instance?

Comment: Yes, but the nullstellensatz gives us the maximal ideal of $(a,b)$ in $k[x,y]$ is of the form $(x-a,y-b)$. How about quotient ring? Is it $(x-p_1,y-p_2,z-p_3)/ (zx-1,-y^n+x^{n-1}-1)$?

Comment: Yes, this is characterization of maximal ideals as those which produce a field after taking the quotient plus the third isomorphism theorem: $A/B\cong (A/C)/(B/C)$.

Comment: It is enough to specify $y$ and a nonzero $x$, as the relation $xz-1$ fixes $z$ for you. (In other words, $z=x^{-1}$ where appropriate.)

Comment: No, it's $(x-p_1,y-p_2,z-p_1^{-1})$ for the "numerator" of that expression.

Comment: Thank you @KReiser